# How to open images in webserver

Tags: go

I have a simple webserver and I want to open imagesin browser. The problem is browser can't open an image I sent.

```
package main

import (

  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http"
  "io"
  "html/template"
  "fmt"

 )  
func main() {



http.HandleFunc("/images", images)


http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
func images(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/link.html")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
    return
}

t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "link", nil)
}
```

Also my html template package, where I create a link to file on my computer. Called link.html

```
  {{ define "link" }}


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <p> <a href="/images/2.jpg">apple</a></p>
   <br>

   </body>
   </html>


   {{ end }}
```

I do not understand why it doesn't work. Will be very glad for help. In addition all files I wanted to add to server are lying in this golang project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you **do not** have *any* dedicated route that handles requests for *any* images.

My recommendation would be to initialize an HTTP handler that serves file based on the URI pathname. You can use that handler as a way to serve images.

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("images"))
```

And then to bind it:

```
http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", fs))
```

Here's your full code with my suggestions:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  // We're creating a file handler, here.
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("images"))

  http.HandleFunc("/images", images)

  // We're binding the handler to the `/images` route, here.
  http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", fs))

  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func images(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/link.html")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
    return
  }

  t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "link", nil)
}
```